# JTextField is not reading the data input by the user

Tags: java, swing

Here I am trying to make a Swing Java app, where I am getting a `String` from the `JTextField t1` and comparing it whether it matches with any other string in a text file and then displaying the matched `String` in the `JTextField t2`. However, the JTextField t1 doesn't even reads the input by the user(I have tried even displaying the input by the user)
**Note:-**There is no problem with the 'main' or with the GUI of this program.

```
JButton b1;
JTextField t1,t2;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){try{
    String a=t1.getText();
    String search="";
    try{
        if(a.length()!=0){
           search=atomicnumber(a);
           t2.setText(a);}
        }catch(Exception x){System.out.println("Error");}

}catch (Exception x) {System.err.println("An Unexpected error encountered."+x);}
}
public static String atomicnumber(String a){try{
              boolean found=false;
              File atmno=new File("C:/Users/DELL/Periodic/text/AtomicNumber.txt");
              String e;
                  Scanner sc=new Scanner(atmno);
             while((e = sc.nextLine()) != null){
                  if (e.startsWith(a)){
                found=true;
                return e;//break;
                }
                  return("0");}}catch(IOException x){}
return("0");}
}
```

Comment: Your method doesn't take a parameter. If it doesn't take in a parameter, you will never be able to call it with an argument.

Comment: I added a `static String a` to make this compile, I didn't attempt to run or analyze your code to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create instance variable **a**  and set this variable in the method `actionPerformed`  and use this instance variable in another method `atomicnumber` .

You need to make the method `atomicnumber` as non-static to access it.

Comment: Can you define 'global variable'?

Comment: did not downvote but global vars aare bad. why not pass a param - by editing the method?

Comment: global mean instance variable and @tgkprog it will be much better if OP can change the struture of the method

Comment: Then you should probably change your answer to clearly state *instance variable* since that makes the difference between an okay solution and a horrible solution.

Comment: Thanks I was able to import the variable.Ok so I found a new problem with working of this program...that the textfield is not even reading the input...so,(I have added the action listeners correctly) what might be the real problem...?

Answer (score 0):

You make an instance variable. You need to make it 'visible'. Also where is your startsWith method? Make sure you are passing the correct parameters.

pseudo code

```
class SomeClass {
    var1 < THIS IS an instance method accessible to any method in that class

method1 {
    var2

}

method2 {
   something.doSomeMethodOn(var2) <<<<< THIS is NOT accessible
   something.doSomeMethodON(var1)<<< THIS IS!
}
```

Comment: `.startsWith()` is a method defined in the `String` class.

Answer (score 0):

In your actionperformed method you are creating a second *String a variable* in another scope : the scope of that function. So you are not initializing the value to static String a but to String a (function scope). In the atomicNumber() function you are referencing the static String a variable which is not initialized...
Try following solution, change:

*String a = t1.getText();*

To

*a = t1.getText();*